# Changing field dynamically in Django's Admin panel

Tags: django

I have a Model with 2 CharFields : `type` and `category`.
Both have `choices` with few possible values.
For example: `type` can get "Article" or "Video" and `category` can get "Extreme", "Funny" or "Amazing".

When an admin needs to add an entry, I want to first show him a list with the possible choices of `types`. Then, if he chooses "Article" I would like to show him another list box which only contains "Extreme" or "Amazing". If he chooses "Video" I want to show him "Funny" or "Amazing".

The idea is to change the list box of `category` dynamically, based on the user's chice of the desired `type`.

Is that possible?

Meir

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's possible. But you have to do it in Javascript. Serverside python code can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

(a) You must use javascript on the client side to do that on the page

(b) You should therefore also write custom validation to ensure that a valid combination is selected. Your `ModelAdmin` subclass should have a member `form`, which should be a custom `ModelForm` with its own implementation of `clean`.